# Function is run multiple times, but only called once

Tags: assembly, nasm

I'm writing a 16-bit real mode assembly application.

Here is the top of the code:

```
org 100h
jmp start

%include "memory.asm"

str: db "aBc", 0
outstr: times 100 db 0

start:
    mov si, str
    mov di, outstr
    call english_to_morse
    jmp $
```

As you can see, I am only calling `english_to_morse` once.

Here is the `english_to_morse` function:

```
english_to_morse:
    pusha
    call str_to_lower

    pusha;             BREAKPOINT
    mov ah, 0Eh
    mov al, 'a'
    int 10h
    popa

.next:
    lodsb
    push si;                get_morse_from_alpha will trash SI

    cmp al, 0
    je .end
    cmp al, 'a'
    jl .next
    cmp al, 'z'
    jg .next

    call get_morse_from_alpha
    call print_morse_letter

    pop si
    jmp .next

.end:
    ret
```

As you can see here, the only looping that is done here is on the `.next` label; not the entire subroutine.

However, when I run this, here is the output:

```
a._  _..._._.
```

About a hundred times (basically, this is just printed over and over again until is suddenly stops).

My goal is for this function to only be run a single time.

---

This was assembled with the NASM assembler and executed in DOSBOX.

Comment: I couln't two pusha's and one popa. Not very logical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the beginning of `english_to_morse` you've got a `pusha`, but there's no corresponding `popa` before the `ret`.

Answer (score 2):

I see 2 problems with your code.

- As Michael pointed out `pusha` is not matched by a `popa`.
- You push the SI register too early.

  1. Both `jl .next` and `jg .next` will keep pushing an extra SI register that will never be popped!
  2. The `je .end` forgets to pop the SI register.

Since you know that **get_morse_from_alpha will trash SI** just put `push si` directly above it's call.

```
.next:
 lodsb
 cmp al, 0
 je .end
 cmp al, 'a'
 jl .next
 cmp al, 'z'
 jg .next
 push si;                get_morse_from_alpha will trash SI
 call get_morse_from_alpha
 call print_morse_letter
 pop si
 jmp .next
.end:
 popa
 ret
```

I can't help noticing that you used signed comparisons. In this little code snippet no harm is done but if ever you want to consider the full ASCII range [0,255] this habit will bring you into trouble. Better use `jb` and `ja`.